# SUMIFS Formula that would check multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet and am attempting to incorporate a SUMIFS formula which would check one column for an condition then check another group of columns to see in the match a condition in order to sum all the values which are > 50000 in the group of columns then multiply those values by 0.084.
My formula returns the #VALUE error. How can I achieve what i want?

```
A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I

NO                    51000 52000 12000 10000 53000

NO                    23000 48000 54000 55000 50000

=SUMIFS(E10:I610,A10:A610,"No",E10:I610,">50000")
```

Help please...

Comment: Nice question - I have a "hack" (hence not posting it as a solution) that'll get you there - Add into column J a sumif along the lines of `=SUMIF(E10:I10,">50000",E10:I10)` and drag it down and then just do a sumif of column J based upon Column A... Again, not a single-formula solution, but it will do the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(IF(A10:A610="N",1,0)*IF(E10:I610>50000,1,0)*E10:I610)
```

The above when used as array formula (by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, instead of <kbd>enter</kbd>) works too.

Answer (score 5):

You can switch it to a SUMPRODUCT formula, which can handle the multiple columns:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(E10:I610*(A10:A610="No")*(E10:I610>50000))
```

EDIT:

Per JosieP, this will work even if there are text values in the range:

```
SUMPRODUCT(E10:I610,(A10:A610="No")*(E10:I610>50000))
```

Comment: Note that this will result in `#VALUE` if there's any text values in E10:I610. In that case you need a `SUM(IF` ... array formula and Barry Houdini. :)

Comment: or a small tweak to `=SUMPRODUCT(E10:I610,(A10:A610="No")*(E10:I610>50000))`

Comment: @barryhoudini thank you-high praise indeed coming from you :-)